# Session management between different Java EE applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have two different Java EE web applications (app1 and app2).

In app1, I have a link called `goApp2`. When the user clicks on this link, app1 has to redirect to app2 with session details. Also, app2 should be able to provide the session details back to the app1 application.

Here we are using Spring "site minder" to get the authentication details. I'm able to get the session details of app1 in app2 when I click the `goApp2` link, but still I have some issues with this.

- How to give a response back to app1 from app2 by using `HttpServletResponse`?
- In case the user is staying in app2 for more time than the configured timeout of app1, then  app2 should send a keep alive request to app1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a URL in App1 which can be called from App2 so as to keep the Session Alive. Then call that URL in App2.

hth